# Unable to populate GridViewDataTextColumn using EF DB model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

this is my first time working with the Code First approach with Entity Framework Models. I'm trying to populate a data grid with user info but the grid column isn't displaying any info.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="Customer_Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="170px" >
 <Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Name="CustomerName" VisibleIndex="0">
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
 </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**Here's my code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      ecdevelopmentEntities DB = new ecdevelopmentEntities();
      Customer_Grid.DataSource = DB.Customers.ToList();
      Customer_Grid.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Comment: Does DB.Customers.ToList() have data?

Comment: I guess the `GridViewDataTextColumn` should expose some property to bind to a property of the item, by searching around it may be the `FieldName` property. Try setting it to one of the property of `Customer`